# Timeout fwrite call to keep it from blocking

Tags: c++, c, blocking, fwrite

Is there a method to keep fwrite from blocking, like say using timeouts?

The scenario is this: I need to make a fwrite call (since I am largely reusing a code , I need to stick to it) on a network. However if I pull off the network cable, the fwrite blocks. Is there a workaround? Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your OS will support it.  Not the standard C or C++ libraries.

Comment: The code would be running on linux, mostly ubuntu

Comment: Put it in your question, not a comment, and use the right tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should have the same effect as @Alexander Bakulin's suggestion, but is somewhat shorter.

```
int fd = fdnum(stream);
int ioctl( fd, FIONBIO, 1 );
```

Reference: http://oss.org.cn/ossdocs/gnu/linux/syscalls_17.html

Answer (score 5):

Switch an underlying file descriptor to non-blocking mode:

```
int fd = fdnum(stream);
int f = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
f |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, f);
```

After this a call to `fwrite()` will immediately return and set `errno` to EAGAIN if the file descriptor is not ready for being written to. Calling it in a loop and using sleeps you can easily implement whatever timeout behavior you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a signal handler and use the `alarm()` system call to schedule delivery of that signal, which will interrupt the `fwrite()` call.  Typical usage would look something like:

```
signal(SIGALRM, handle_sigalrm);
received_alarm = 0;
alarm(10);
...some blocking operation...
alarm(0); // cancel the alarm.
if (received_alarm) {
  // command timed out
} else {
  // command completed successfully
}
```

This assumes that `handle_sigalrm()` is a function that sets the `received_alarm` global variable when called. [Google](http://encrypted.google.com/search?q=sigalarm+timeout) has some examples.

This is absolutely not the best way to handle this, but it may be your only option if you're forced to use `fwrite()`.  A better solution is to use a `select()` or `poll()` loop and non-blocking sockets, but that may require a substantial redesign of your code.